# flex.l:17:8: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘YYSTYPE’ {aka ‘int’}) "int" {yylval->fn = 11; return TYPE; }

Tags: compiler-errors, bison, flex-lexer

I'm tring to create a compiler in flex and bison, but when i try to compile my code I'm getting this type of error
how can i resolve this problem??

```
flex.l:17:8: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘YYSTYPE’ {aka ‘int’}) "int" {yylval->fn = 11; return TYPE; }
```

this is flex file

```
%option header-file="flex.lex.h"
%{
  #include "bison.tab.h"
  #include "dichiarazioni.h"
 %}
 %%
 "global_variables" { return VAR; }
 "events"   { return EVENT; }
 "commands"             { return COMMAND; }
 "state"                    { return STATE; }
 "actions"              { return ACTION; }
 "char" {yylval->fn = 10; return TYPE; }
 "int"  {yylval->fn = 11; return TYPE; }
 "float"    { yylval->fn = 12; return TYPE; }
 "double" { yylval->fn = 13; return TYPE; }
 "void" { yylval->fn = 14; return TYPE; }
 "inc"                  { yylval->fn = 24; return OPERATORE; }
 "dec"                  { yylval->fn = 25; return OPERATORE; }
 "set"                  { yylval->fn = 26; return OPERATORE; } 
 print_schermo_message  { yylval->fn = 40; return PRINT; }
 [0-9]+                     { return NUMBER; }
 ([a-z]+[_a-z0-9]*)     { return ALPHA; }
 "+"                        { yylval->fn = 20; return OPERATORE; }
 "-"                        { yylval->fn = 21; return OPERATORE; }
 "*"                        { yylval->fn = 22; return OPERATORE; }
 "/"                     { yylval->fn = 23; return OPERATORE; }
 ">"            { yylval->fn = 1; return CMP; }
 "<"            { yylval->fn = 2; return CMP; }
 "!="           { yylval->fn = 3; return CMP; }
 "=="           { yylval->fn = 4; return CMP; }
 ">="           { yylval->fn = 5; return CMP; }
 "<="           { yylval->fn = 6; return CMP; }
 "&&"           { yylval->fn = 7; return CMP; }
 "||"           { yylval->fn = 8; return CMP; }
%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the semantic value (`yylval`) is normally defined in tbe grammar file using a `%union` declaration. Since you don't show your grammar file, it's impossible to be more precise about what's wrong but the fact that the compiler believes that `yylval` is an `int` suggests that you have not provided any declaration. (`int` is the default type.)

In any case, unless you have requested a reentrant parser, `yylval` will normally be a `union` (or scalar) and not a pointer.

Please see the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Semantics.html#Semantics) for more details on how you declare and use semantic values.